# Can I automatically generate an Euler (Venn) diagram from a containment graph

Tags: graph, 2d, data-visualization, diagram, venn-diagram

Say I have a directed graph G where each node represents some set I've got.
There is an edge from u to v iff u is a subset of v.
This graph is transitive and acyclic. There are a number of source nodes (ones which don't contain any of the other nodes), and one sink (a big "unverse" set containing the union of all the others.).
In other words, this graph is the transitive orientation of a [comparability graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph).

What I want to know is, can I automatically generate a nice looking Euler diagram from this graph?

An [Euler diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) is like a Venn diagram, but you don't have to show every combination of overlap between the sets.

An example is something like this (taken from wikipedia):

[image]

I'm sure I could make diagrams like this by hand, but I'm dealing with large data sets
that I will be constantly adding to, so I'd like to automate the process.
Note that the relative size of the diagrams is not important to me,
only whether two regions overlap, are mutually exclusive, or if one is contained in the other.

Are there algorithms, tools or libraries which allow me to do this?

Please note that I've asked a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116930/how-to-automatically-generate-venn-diagrams-given-the-inclusion-relations), but I've most of my responses have been that LaTeX is simply not the right tool for this job. Thus, I'm asking it here.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a Euler diagram is essentially an incomplete Venn diagram. Some intersections are deemed unimportant and are thrown away. Do you have a criterion to decide which intersections are unimportant? Otherwise, how could an algorithm know?

Comment: I was thinking that the intersection of two sets would be assumed to be empty unless otherwise specified, and empty intersections would be ignored in the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

"Euler diagrams are difficult to draw automatically, and it is a goal of this project to produce the first method for drawing all Euler diagrams nicely." – from [eulerdiagrams.com](http://www.eulerdiagrams.com/), but there are a few links there.

Other than that, searching for `Euler diagram generation` seems to bring up some results, like [Vennerable](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/vennerable/). But judging from this [2008 paper](http://kar.kent.ac.uk/15622/1/EulerRogers.pdf), it is still a rather active area in research.

Answer (score 0):

You might find your solution here : [`SageMath`](http://www.sagemath.org/). This is a very powerful Math engine witch allow you to draw a lot of diagram.

Comment: Cool tool, any idea or instructions on how to use it to draw the Euler diagram?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just helped to implement a part of `LaTeX`support but you should find it quite quickly!